# Set figure path in knitr chunk options in bookdown

Tags: r, filepath, figure, bookdown

I want to set the filepath for all my images for a large document.

This is my yaml and r setup:

````
---
title: "General Introduction"
csl: harvard-cite-them-right.csl
header-includes:
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \newcommand{\blandscape}{\begin{landscape}}
- \newcommand{\elandscape}{\end{landscape}}
- \usepackage{lmodern}
- \usepackage{graphicx}

output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    keep_tex: yes
    latex_engine: xelatex
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: '2'
  html_document: default
  word_document:
    reference_docx: my-styles.docx
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 2
mainfont: Arial
fontsize: 11pt
bibliography: library.bib
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, fig.path = "figs&tabs/")
````

I am trying to include an image as follows:

````
```{r ed, fig.cap = '(ref:roum)' , out.width='100%' }
knitr::include_graphics("ed.png")
````

but the file is not found. It works if I include the filepath within the chunk but I don't want to do this everytime as multiple images:

````
```{r ed, fig.cap = '(ref:roum)' , out.width='100%' }
knitr::include_graphics("figs&tabs/ed.png")
````

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you expect something different from that command/setting. `fig.path` := a file path to the directory where knitr should store the graphics files **created by the chunk**. In other words, this saves you from defining the path when saving the plots created by the chunk. If you want to read them in you need the "full" path. If this is too troublesome for you, define a short wrapper function that appends the prefix for you and does the include. P.S. I recommend to not use special characters like the & in your folder name ... also this time it works. Just beware of some special characters,

Comment: @Ray thanks for the advice. Could you give me an idea how I could write a wrapper function like that?

Comment: Actually I've figured it out: `fpath = function(x) {paste("figs_and_tabs/", x, sep = "")}`

Comment: awesome. Good to see that you beat me :)  ... You could have even put the `knitr::include...()` call inside your function. But that is a question of style/how much to wrap. Think about adding an answer  and describing your solution. This way this post is closeable with an answer. Well done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fig.path` option in `knitr::opts_chunk$set` is used to set the file path to *save* plots to.

To set a file path in the r setup chunk I created a wrapper function:

```
fpath = function(x) {paste("figs_and_tabs/", x, sep = "")}
```

and insert the image with:

````
```{r ed, fig.cap = '(ref:roum)' , out.width='100%' }
knitr::include_graphics(fpath("ed.png"))
````

One step further: To set the file path *and* include the  `knitr::include_grpahics` call in the function I used:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
fp = function(x) {knitr::include_graphics(paste("figs_and_tabs/", x, sep = ""))}
````

and then insert the image with

````
```{r ed, fig.cap = '(ref:roum)' , out.width='100%' }
fp("ed.png")
````